# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B which version of linux works properly with .NET Core 3

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi, embedded

I am trying to run .NET Core 3.0 properly on Raspberry Pi 3 B.
First I tried to install CentOS 7 and cannot succeed with .NET Core.
Secondly I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 Server and properly installed .NET Core but whenever I try to run my project its giving me the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load
>   shared library 'System.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order to
>   help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG
>   environment variable: libSystem.Native: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

I'm looking for advice on which Linux distro I need to install on Raspberry Pi to run .NET Core properly on this device.

Comment: I cannot imagine that it is distro dependent rather than simply a matter of ensuring all necessary dependencies are installed. This https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md demonstrates how to do it in Linux and Win10 IoT. The Linux instructions are fairly generic, and do not assume that you are using Rasbian, but some instructions may need modification for different package managers perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

We have deployed .Net Core 3.1 on Raspberry pi's using Raspbian and Diet Pi. They work very good.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

https://dietpi.com/

I strongly suggest you use docker, it will make you life much easier.